# Access variable from foreach in jsp expression

Tags: java, jsp

I wanted to make a small change to a legacy JSP Tiles application. I wanted to display job type computed in Java. So I added JSP code snippet because I could not easily modify the passed Java object:

```
<%@ page import="com.web.controller.JobsHelper" %>
<c:forEach var="job" items="${scheduledJobs}">
    <c:set var="job" value="${job}"/>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="${detailURL}${job.id}">${job.name}</a></td>
        <td>${job.description}</td>
        <td><%= JobsHelper.getJobType(job) %></td>
```

But it failed on a compilation error:

```
An error occurred at line: 90 in the jsp file: /tiles/job/overview.jsp
job cannot be resolved to a variable
89: <td>${job.description}</td>
90: <td><%= JobsHelper.getJobType(job) %></td>
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution was to introduce the JSTL function as tag lib

WEB-INF/functions.tld

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<taglib
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd"
        version="2.1">

    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <short-name>Custom_Functions</short-name>
    <uri>http://company.com/functions</uri>

    <function>
        <name>jobType</name>
        <function-class>com..JobsHelper</function-class>
        <function-signature>java.langString getJobType(com..model.RunRecord)</function-signature>
    </function>
</taglib>
```

JSP

```
<%@taglib uri="http://company.com/functions" prefix="func" %>
<td>
    ${func:jobType(job)}
</td>
```